# Disconnect Firebase from Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile-application

I am currently working on a project, this project is about an android application but it is currently on my friend's GitHub and it is currently connected to Firebase. I am not sure how to disconnect the project from Firebase. If someone could help that would be awesome. Please refer to this screenshot for further information:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database is basically a Google program that hosts a database for you. In terms of being connected, generally we would be talking about a client connection to the host (the database). For that to happen you would have to be coding a program to connect to the database.

Are you talking about programmatically disconnecting the database? If not, I don't believe there's *actually* a connection there. It may just be Firebase telling you that you're on the right track to using the database in your program.

To double check that you aren't connected to the database, go in to your Firebase Console and double check that there isn't any usage happening on the Realtime Database. If there's not, I don't believe there's any connection you need to worry about.

Personally I've worked with Firebase before and used it in programs, and I've never come across a time when Firebase was anything other than a library or API for me to use. I doubt you need to worry!

If you're looking to delete the "App" on Firebase's end, you can go in to the Firebase Console and do that manually as well (to do this, you can go into your Apps card in the Firebase Console and select "Remove this app").

Furthermore, to delete the project itself in the Firebase Console, you can go to General Settings and click "Delete project".